# How to express "There is a specified symbol in the following unknown numbers of characters" in regex(vim)?

Tags: vim, regular-expression

I have many python code examples in my markdown files, which should be prepended with `>>>` symbols.

So I write a vim function to do this job:

```
function AddShellPrompt() range
    let lnum = a:firstline
    while lnum <= a:lastline
        let replaced_line = substitute(getline(lnum), '^\s\+', '&>>>', '')
        call setline(lnum, replaced_line)
        let lnum += 1
    endwhile
endfunction
```

The problem is, for raw text like:

```
pow(2, 3)
8
```

I need only add `>>>` before `pow(2, 3)`, but not before `8`.
So I need to expand my regex.
It comes to me that if I only add `>>>` for a line which contains any character of `+-*/%(=`.
I can get a pretty good result(though not perfect).

But the problem is, how to write regex (especially in vim) which expresses *Some of the characters in the given set has appeared in the current line?*

Comment: Good question!  For vi and vim, you can't also ask at the dedicated site https://vi.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @cxw, if you think it's a good question, vote for me, please. And I'm happy to see there is a dedicated vim site on stackoverflow!

Answer (score 1):

`vim` regex engine support [Bracket Expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05), you can defined a class of characters as a sequence of characters enclosed by square brackets `[...]`:

```
/[+\-*/%(=]/
```

will match any character from those characters (You need to escape `-`, which defined a range between characters, to match it literally)

To check current line contains any in set of characters:

```
if getline(".") =~ '[+\-*/%(=]'
  echo "Match"
endif
```

Comment: Yeah, I know, this is a `meta class`, but how to express: `In the following arbitrary characters, one of the chars in the meta class has appeared`? For example, how to write a regex in vim, which can detect if a line contains any `+`, `%` or `=`?

Comment: @Zen: I'm not sure what do you mean. `if getline(".") =~? '[+%=]'` will match if line contains any `+`, `%` or `=`.

Comment: I got you know. This `if getline(".") =~? '[+%=]' ` is a more complete expression. Especially the `=~?` expression, I didn't know it before. Is it able a even add a word into such kind of meta class? I mean, can I detect if the word `import` exists in the line within the [+%=] expression? Or must I write `if getline(".") =~? '[+%=]' and getline(".") =~? "import"`. If I had to add a whole and block. Wouldn't the work detect if one of the multiple words in a line a tedious job? Or should I write a for loop, put all key words in a list. And check if they are in the line one by one?

Comment: `[...]` is set of characters, not word. Using `if getline(".") =~? '[+%=]`, you only know if line contains *any* of those characters, you don't know if *all* matched or *how many* characters matched.

Comment: I know how meta class works. Anyway, your answer is a solution to my original question. Could you please update `if getline(".") =~? '[+%=]'` to your answer so that I can accept your answer? That's an important update, I think.